# PF firewall issues with FTP inside FreeBSD jail

Tags: firewall, ftp, freebsd, pf, jail

I have recently tried to set up jails on one of my FreeBSD servers, and I’m running into strange errors while trying to download FreeBSD packages via FTP.

I have these rules in the PF firewall to allow the download of packages on the host machine, where they work fine:

```
ext_if = "bge0"

# Allow downloads
pass out log on $ext_if proto tcp to any port {20, 21, 22, 80, 443}

# Special exception for FTP.
pass out log on $ext_if proto tcp to any port > 49151 keep state
```

But when I try to install packages from inside the Jail, the FTP connection just times out.
The error message I get is this:

```
%pkg_add -vr bash
[snipped FTP connection setup]
>>> CWD pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8.1-release/Latest
<<< 250 CWD command successful.
>>> MODE S
<<< 200 MODE S accepted.
>>> TYPE I
<<< 200 Type set to I.
binding data socket
>>> PORT 82,103,140,25,229,3
<<< 200 PORT command successful.
initiating transfer
>>> RETR bash.tbz
<<< 425 Can't build data connection: Operation timed out.
Error: Unable to get ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8.1-release/Latest/bash.tbz: Can't open data connection
pkg_add: unable to fetch 'ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8.1-release/Latest/bash.tbz' by URL
pkg_add: 1 package addition(s) failed
```

Is there some sort of connection I’m missing? I wish I could just configure pkg_add to use HTTP instead of FTP (I have no idea why FreeBSD still uses that sorry excuse for a protocol), but it seems FTP is needed to operate FreeBSDs package system, and I have no idea how to make it work with the firewall. Any suggestions will be welcome :)

Comment: You can use `setenv PACKAGEROOT http://ftp7.us.freebsd.org` if you want to fetch the packages via HTTP (assuming you're using `pkg_add -r {package_name}` . FTP is better at file transfers, therefor FreeBSD uses it.

Comment: Thanks, that works – as for FTP being better at file transfers, I haven’t heard of anything that would make it measurably better than HTTP when doing transfers in the megabyte range…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default FTP uses so called 'Active' mode for data transfer which is not very firewall friendly. In this mode FTP server connects to IP:port specified in PORT command sent by client (82.103.140.25:58627 in your case).

Simplest way to fix this is to switch from 'Active' to 'Passive' FTP transfer mode. In case of 'pkg_add', which uses fetch(1) for file retrieval, it is done by setting environment variable FTP_PASSIVE_MODE.

Comment: Ah, that’s a neat trick, thanks. Where is the best place to set such a variable globally (as to avoid having it in .bashrc, .cshrc, etc. for all admin users)?

Comment: Use /etc/profile for 'sh' and 'bash' or /etc/csh.cshrc and /etc/csh.login for 'csh'. Also, environment can be set through /etc/login.conf. BTW, I've just found that 'default' class in default /etc/login.conf already has FTP_PASSIVE_MODE set.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ftp-proxy(8)` with `anchor "ftp-proxy/*"`

For more info see here http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/ftp.html

Comment: Yeah, I read about this option, but I considered it to be too much of a hassle. I don’t need any more strange services to keep track of :)